# WSO2 ESB From XML (multiple lines) to JSON (without wrappers)

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I hope to find help here...  Here is the particular case:
I get this XML from my Endpoint:

```
<Entries>
    <Entry>
        <Customer>1</Customer>
    </Entry>
    <Entry>
        <Customer>2</Customer>
    </Entry>
<Entries>
```

I can easily convert this XML to JSON by changing the Property messageType, which will result in:

```
{"Entries":{"Entry":[{"Customer": 1}, {"Customer": 2}]}}
```

Here is what I want to get, as a JSON result (without wrappers):

```
[{"Customer": 1}, {"Customer": 2}]
```

Is there someone who knows how?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a payload mediator inside a foreach mediator to construct the JSON from xml.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+18%3A+Transforming+a+Message+Using+ForEach+Mediator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Anuruddha and Nicolas!
Your answers inspired me and I want to share what I did.

I have created this sequence, which I reuse with a Sequence mediator:

```
<sequence name="toJSON" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="result" scope="default" type="STRING" expression="json-eval($.Entries.Entry)"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>$1</format>
        <args>
            <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:result"/>
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
</sequence>
```

It works so well I even changed the sequence of all my Proxies, even those that returns only 1 result.

Many thanks for your lights!!

Answer (score 1):

I think you've to first manipulate your xml (maybe with an xslt mediator) to format it this way

```
<jsonArray>
    <Customer>1</Customer>
    <Customer>2</Customer>
</jsonArray>
```

Then I guess you'll get your expected output.

For instance the following xslt could do the job

```
<xsl:stylesheet exclude-result-prefixes="xsl" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>     
    <xsl:template match="/Entries">
        <xsl:element name="jsonArray">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./Entry/Customer" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```